# Handling SQL injections

Tags: php, sql-injection

What is better (more secure) way to handle SQL injections ?

```
$var = filter_var($_POST['var'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

or

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['var']);
```

Comment: Use prepared statements and bind variables.

Comment: I've used prepared statements. Just wondering if it's the only way to ensure security.

Comment: There are some well read (and written) posts on SQL injection, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection?rq=1, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Comment: Not the only way, just the best.